# How to paste a stored range to next free column and certain rows?

Tags: excel, range, vba

I've been stuck with this problem for a while and I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me.

So here's what I want to do with this macro.

1. Get data from two different ranges from sheet "Overtime"
2. Store these data ranges next to each other in sheet "Summary"
   2.1 The main idea is that the macro stores data to the Summary sheet next to the last entry.

I'm able to do this when I define the range as .Range("E5:E37") but I need to change the predefined column to the next empty one, how to do that?

I tried to change the Range to Range(.Cells(5, CheckCol), .Cells(37, CheckCol)) but that doesn't work.

Sorry if the code looks messed up, I just started with VBA and the end part is a bit messed up since I didn't know what to do :D Here's what I've done so far.

```
Sub Transfer_Data_1()
'
' Transfer_Data_1 Macro

' Locate cells on a row
PasteToCol = Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
PasteToCol2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
CheckCol = Sheets("Summary").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' Locate the last stored date
CheckDateOLD = Sheets("Summary").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

' Store date values and hours
OvertimeDateOLD = Sheets("Summary").Cells(6, CheckDateOLD).Value
OvertimeTotal = Sheets("Overtime").Cells(40, 7).Value
OvertimeTotalOLD = Sheets("Summary").Cells(37, CheckCol).Value

Set OvertimeDatesNEW = GetDates(Sheets("Overtime"), 8, 2, 40)
Set OvertimeHoursNEW = GetHours(Sheets("Overtime"), 8, 7, 40)

'Convert entered date to month name
OvertimeDate2 = Sheets("Overtime").Cells(9, 2).Value
OvertimeDate = MonthName(Month(OvertimeDate2))

' Check if the values were already there and paste accordingly if not
If OvertimeDateOLD = OvertimeDate And OvertimeTotalOLD = OvertimeTotal Then
    MsgBox "These results have already been updated"
ElseIf OvertimeDateOLD = OvertimeDate And OvertimeTotalOLD <> OvertimeTotal Then
    Sheets("Summary").Range(5, PasteToCol).Value = OvertimeDatesNEW
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, PasteToCol).Value = OvertimeHoursNEW
    MsgBox "Data for this month has been updated"
ElseIf OvertimeDateOLD <> OvertimeDate And OvertimeTotalOLD <> OvertimeTotal Then
    Sheets("Summary").Range(.Cells(5, CheckCol), .Cells(37, CheckCol)).Value = OvertimeDatesNEW.Value
    Sheets("Summary").Range("F5:F37").Value = OvertimeHoursNEW.Value
    MsgBox "Results have been stored to Summary"
End If

End Sub
```

The two functions are used to get value from two ranges. It could have been done more easily I guess but I wanted to test functions as well as I'm doing this to learn something.

```
>Function GetDates(Overtime As Worksheet, StartRow As Integer, StartCol As Integer, EndRow >As Integer)
>Dim DataTableDates As Range
>
>Set DataTableDates = Overtime.Range(Overtime.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), >Overtime.Cells(EndRow, StartCol))
>Set GetDates = DataTableDates
>End Function
>
>Function GetHours(Overtime As Worksheet, StartRow As Integer, StartCol As Integer, EndRow >As Integer)
>Dim DataTableHours As Range
>
>Set DataTableHours = Overtime.Range(Overtime.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), >Overtime.Cells(EndRow, StartCol))
>Set GetHours = DataTableHours
>End Function
```

Comment: what errors are you getting - or tell us what the expected behavior is and the actual results then we try to help

Comment: You are making calls to functions and do not include them in your code. `GetDates()` and `GetHours` are not defined. Will you please provide them?

Comment: Added functions in the first post. So basically what I'm asking is how to define a range so that it's always the next free column instead of a predefined column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added a `.` before `Cells` in `Sheets("Summary").Range(.Cells(5, CheckCol), .Cells(37, CheckCol)).Value = OvertimeDatesNEW.Value`

You might want to try

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range(Cells(5, CheckCol), Cells(37, CheckCol)).Value = OvertimeDatesNEW.Value
Range("F5:F37").Value = OvertimeHoursNEW.Value
```

or

```
With Sheets("Summary")
    .Range(.Cells(5, CheckCol), .Cells(37, CheckCol)).Value = OvertimeDatesNEW.Value
    .Range("F5:F37").Value = OvertimeHoursNEW.Value
End With
```

Here is an example:

```
Sub FindLastCol()
    Dim LastCol As Integer

    'Find the first empty column in row 1 on the active sheet
    LastCol = Rows(1).Columns(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    'Set Rows 1 through 50 in the first empty column to "Example"
    Range(Cells(1, LastCol), Cells(50, LastCol)) = "Example"
End Sub
```